# Can't open a java file in terminal

Tags: java, jar

I have java installed but when I try to open it in terminal it doesn't work

I type

```
java -jar Minecraft.jar
```

the output I get is

```
unable to get access to jar file Minecraft.jar
```

How I could fix this so I can next time just click the app. My operating system is Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Minecraft.jar` file must be in your current working directory, which seems not being the case. So you either change your working directory to where `Minecraft.jar` resides or give full path to it

```
java --jar /your/valid/full/path/to/Minecraft.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

give the full path to jar or go to directory and run command `java -jar Minecraft.jar`.